# Loop only checks last value of a vector in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

Im quite new in R and I think my question is rather easy, but I hope someone can help me.

I made a vector that contains unique client id's who have converted. Furthermore I have a df with sessionid of all customers, so customers who have converted and not converted.

I want to make a new df that has only sessions with client id's that have converted. To do this I thought a loop would be a good solution. However, it only checks the last value of the vector.

The code I used:

```
#Create vector that contains unique client id's that converted
Client_id_conversion_vector <- unique(Test$ClientId)

#Loop that creates new df 
for (i in (Client_id_conversion_vector)){ 
  Sessions_of_clients_who_converted <- (Sessions[Sessions$ClientId== i ])
  }
```

I add an example to make it more clear:

```
Sessions    ClienID     Conversion
1              1             No
2              1             No
3              2             No
4              2            Yes
5              3             No
6              3             Yes
```

In the end I want something like:

```
Sessions    ClienID     Conversion
3              2             No
4              2            Yes
5              3             No
6              3             Yes
```

So I want to make a new df with all the sessions of clients who have converted once.

Thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: Please add some sample data: Input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
#data
sessions <- 1:6
client <- 1:3
client <- sort(append(client,client))
conversion <- c("No","No","No","Yes","No","Yes")
df <- data.frame(sessions,client,conversion)
```

One-line answer

```
df[df$client %in% unique(df$client[df$conversion == "Yes"]),]
```

Step-by-step

Get  list of converted clients, I assume you might have duplicate values and use unique

```
index <- unique(df$client[df$conversion == "Yes"])
```

Filter your dataframe for converted clients

```
df[df$client %in% index,]
```

Comment: When I use this code the result gives me a large list. I want to have a dataframe that shows all the variables I have for the clientId's of my vector. Is it also possible to get a df like that as a result?

Comment: You could do it inside the loop or convert the vector into a dataframe.
To convert into a dataframe:

Sessions_of_clients_who_converted <- data.frame(ID = Sessions_of_clients_who_converted)

Comment: Its not really working. I edited my post tot make more clear what i want. Is a loop like this also applicable for that?

Comment: This line works:

df[df$client %in% unique(df$client[df$conversion == "Yes"]),]

I will edit my answer to show it step by step. You don't need a loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `Sessions_with_conversion` each time the loop iterates. However, it would be better to do this without a loop at all. You can make use of the vectorization inherent in R to make your code shorter and run more quickly. Your loop can be replaced with a more efficient alternative:

```
Sessions_of_converted <- Sessions[Sessions$Client_Id %in% Client_id_conversion_vector,]
```

---

You didn't provide any sample data, so here's a full reproducible example:

```r
set.seed(69)
Sessions <- data.frame(Client_Id = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 8, replace = TRUE),
                       Data = 1:8, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Sessions
#>   Client_Id Data
#> 1         A    1
#> 2         C    2
#> 3         B    3
#> 4         A    4
#> 5         C    5
#> 6         C    6
#> 7         C    7
#> 8         B    8
Client_id_conversion_vector <- c("A", "B")

Sessions[Sessions$Client_Id %in% Client_id_conversion_vector,]
#>   Client_Id Data
#> 1         A    1
#> 3         B    3
#> 4         A    4
#> 8         B    8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Sorry for not providing any data example. I edited my post to make it more clear.